# react navigation v3 set screenProps through AppContainer

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I need to pass theme settings to navigation options of each screen. Settings are stored in redux. In old version I would write something like that:

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: MainList },
  Settings: { screen: Settings },
  NewEvent: { screen: NewEvent },
  Contacts: { screen: Contacts },
  Map: { screen: Map},
})
```

And in render function...

```
<AppNavigator 
   screenProps={{
     settings: this.props.settings,
     headerTintColor: '#ffffff'
   }}
/>
```

...where props.settings is a part of redux state. Which is used inside navigationOptions

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => {
  let settings = screenProps.settings;
  let theme = settings? settings.theme: null;

  return {
    title: strings.account,
    headerTintColor: screenProps.headerTintColor,
    headerStyle: {backgroundColor: theme? theme.def.primaryColor: null}
  };
};
```

But how should I do this now when I must wrap my Navigators with createAppContainer? Using navigation.setParams makes a visible delay in emulator so its not a proper solution for me... Keep in mind theme can be changed at any time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well) Turnsout you can achive that by creating a custom navigator like this:

```
class NavWrapper extends Component {
  static router = AppNavigator.router;
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    return <AppNavigator
      navigation={navigation}
      screenProps={{
        settings: this.props.settings,
        headerTintColor: '#ffffff'
      }}
    />;
  }
}

const AppNavWrapper = connect(state => ({settings: state.settings}))(NavWrapper);
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavWrapper);
```

And then in your root component

```
render() {
  return (
    <AppContainer/>
  );
}
```

Hope that helps :)