# Using Redux state in defaultNavigationOptions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am using React-navigation and redux in my app.

I have to change header color according to state. I have saved color inside state and my colors came from Api call.

I have used navigationOptions with redux according to docs.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: "MyApp",
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: navigation.getParam('primary_color'),
    },
    headerTintColor: navigation.getParam('primary_color_text')
})

componentWillMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
        ...this.props.appSettings
    });
}
```

But I'm getting white header for 1 sec then my color one, due to props setting by params. So is there any way I can connect `defaultNavigationOptions`?

Comment: What is the default color you want to have? Is it a fixed color or the one returned from the API call?

Comment: @Remeus return from api which can be changed from backend

Comment: I'm not familiar with `react-navigation` but do you pass in the default colour as a prop?

Comment: If the color is returned from the API then there will always be a small delay during which the parameter is not defined. A solution can be to display a loading screen until the color is returned from the backend, for instance by having a `if` condition in the render function.

Comment: @Remeus color is already grabbed from api and store is redux but this delay due to setting props by setParams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `defaultNavigationOptions` in the same way you do `navigationOptions`, any parameters you set can be accessed there as well.

```js
defaultNavigationOptions = ({ navigationData }) => {
    let params = navigationData.navigation.state.params || {...yourDefaultParams};

    return {
        title: "MyApp",
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: params["primary_color"],
        },
        headerTintColor: params["primary_color_text"],
    };
});
```

It will, however give the same delay on changing the colors. You will have to attack the problem from a different angle. **Have a look a Edward Starlight's suggested solution:**

[react navigation v3 set screenProps through AppContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53377536/react-navigation-v3-set-screenprops-through-appcontainer/53377914#53377914)

> You can achieve that by creating a custom navigator like this:
>
> ```
> class NavWrapper extends Component {
>   static router = AppNavigator.router;
>   render() {
>     const { navigation } = this.props;
>
>     return <AppNavigator
>       navigation={navigation}
>       screenProps={{
>         settings: this.props.settings,
>         headerTintColor: '#ffffff'
>       }}
>     />;
>   }
> }
>
> const AppNavWrapper = connect(state => ({settings: state.settings}))(NavWrapper);
> const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavWrapper);
> ```
>
> And then in your root component
>
> ```
> render() {
>   return (
>     <AppContainer/>
>   );
> }
> ```